# Вывести содержание записи на страницу шаблона средством ajax

Tags: content, запись, post, wordpress, ajax

Добрый день.

Нашла инструкцию по работе ajax-запросов в wordpresse.
Попробовала реализовать, и все вышло, как и было, по инструкции.
http://wp-kama.ru/id_652/dinamicheskiy-arhiv-bloga-s-ispolzovaniem-jquery-ajax.html

Сейчас пытаюсь изменить код, чтобы по событию change загружал одну определенную запись, т.е. ее содержание.

```
// Получаем данные с помощью query_posts
        query_posts("posts_per_page=-1&cat=$cat&monthnum=$month&year=$year");
        //$page_data = get_page( $page_id );
        //$post = get_posts(11914)->post_content;
        // выводим данные в Цикле WordPress
        $id = 11914;// Обязательно передавать переменную
        $post = get_post($id); 
        $content = $post->post_content;
        if( have_posts() ){ echo "<tr><td>$page_data->post_content</td></tr>";
            while( have_posts() )
                { 
                    the_post(); 
                    the_content();?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'><?php the_title(); the_content(); ?></a></td>
                        <td><?php comments_popup_link(' ', '1 Комментарий', '% Комментариев'); ?></td>
                        <td><?php the_time('j.m.Y');$content ?></td>
                    </tr>
                     <div class="entry"></div>
                <?php
            }}
```

Но у меня так и не подгружает контент записи, подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Нашла решение:

```
$post_id = 8994;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
$content = $queried_post->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
echo $content;
```